# How to calculate the mean value of a 4-D tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just used TensorFlow to realise a CNN model. Here, I have a tensor with 4 dimensions: A=[16,96,96,64] (16 is the batch size, 96 is the image block size, and 64 is the number of feature maps). I just need to calculate the mean value(like a average pooling) of each feature map in tensor A and return a new tensor with size of [16,1,1,64] and it contains the mean value of each feature map in A.

Could you please let me know how I realise this?

Thanks in advance!

A tensor with size of [16,96,96,64] and I need to get the mean value of each feature map in this tensor and return a tensor with a size of [16,1,1,64]. I am not sure how to realise this.

The result should be the tensor including the mean values of feature maps in tensor A, and it has the size of [16,1,1,64].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.reduce_mean()` with specified argument `axis` to compute mean and then `tf.expand_dims()` to restore the reduced axis:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 96, 96, 64))

reduced = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1), 1)
reduced = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(reduced, axis=2), 2)

data = np.random.normal(size=(16, 96, 96, 64))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    evaled = reduced.eval({x:data})
    print(evaled.shape) # (16, 1, 1, 64)
```